How to make ajax Post without open the page
I try to make Ajax post URl using toDataURL, ajax call is made in test.php. My save function is on save.php. My problem is the image can be save if i open test.php first, then the image will appear in my directory. What i want is saving the image when open save.php. Is it possible to do that?
test.php
function submitdata(){
var canvas = document.getElementById('chart1');
var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png', 1);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", 
            url: "save.php",
            data: { imgData: imgData },
            success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            }
        });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    submitdata();
}); 

save.php
function save_base64_image($base64_image_string, $output_file_without_extension, $path_with_end_slash="" ) {

    $splited = explode(',', substr( $base64_image_string , 5 ) , 2);
    $mime=$splited[0];
    $data=$splited[1];

    $mime_split_without_base64=explode(';', $mime,2);
    $mime_split=explode('/', $mime_split_without_base64[0],2);
    if(count($mime_split)==2)
    {
        $extension=$mime_split[1];
        if($extension=='jpeg')$extension='jpg';
        $output_file_with_extension=$output_file_without_extension.'.'.$extension;
    }
    file_put_contents( $path_with_end_slash . $output_file_with_extension, base64_decode($data) );
    return $output_file_with_extension;
}

$image = $_POST['imgData'];

$path='images/chart_1';

save_base64_image($image, $path, $path_with_end_slash="" );

I also try to use this function
function save_base64_image($base64_image_string, $output_file_without_extension, $path_with_end_slash="" ) {

    $splited = explode(',', substr( $base64_image_string , 5 ) , 2);
    $mime=$splited[0];
    $data=$splited[1];

    $mime_split_without_base64=explode(';', $mime,2);
    $mime_split=explode('/', $mime_split_without_base64[0],2);
    if(count($mime_split)==2)
    {
        $extension=$mime_split[1];
        if($extension=='jpeg')$extension='jpg';
        $output_file_with_extension=$output_file_without_extension.'.'.$extension;
    }
    file_put_contents( $path_with_end_slash . $output_file_with_extension, base64_decode($data) );
    return $output_file_with_extension;
}

$image = $_POST['imgData'];

$x1=   chr(rand(0,25)+97) ;
$x2=   chr(rand(0,25)+97) ;
$x3=   chr(rand(0,25)+97) ;
$x4=   chr(rand(0,9)+48) ;
$x5=   chr(rand(0,9)+48) ;

$path = 'images/';
$filename = $path . 'chart1_' . $x1 . $x2 . $x3 . $x4 . $x5.'.png';

save_base64_image($image, $path, $filename);


my image is save when i open save.php but my image did not contain anything (blank).

your question is not clear

which part is not clear?

@Unknown, if I understood your question correctly, you're opening save.php directly (without the Ajax call). If you do that, nothing will be sent to your save_base64_image function (because the $_POST['imgData'] will be null).

yes it is. So do you have any suggestion on how to deal with it. Because what i want to do is directly open the page where save_base64_image function

The logic of save.php code is catch the $_POST['imgData'] content and save the image file. If you open save.php directly, nothing will be sent. The only way to use this file with direct access is changing the $_POST variable to $_GET, and send the image content as a parameter (ex save.php?imgData=img-base64).

So, is it true that your main target is to use a single php page (instead of two pages) to do the whole canvas saving process ?

@KenLee its true. But since its impossible to do so, i will try another way.

It is possible (I think there are two methods, at least) by merging the two pages together

If it possible, can you tell me how to do it. What do you mean by merging the two page?

Hi @Unknown, see my answer below (showing the code of the two methods)

Since your main purpose is to accomplish "saving the image" of the canvas, but due to some special reasons you do not want to use two separate pages (one HTML and one PHP), we may merge the required functions into a single PHP file which performs both of the following

generating the canvas
saving the image file

There are two slightly different methods to do the above, one involves ajax and one does not.
For both of the two methods, it will generate and save the png file into a folder known as "images", so make sure you have this folder and make sure this folder is writable by the system
Method 1 - use ajax (calling itself)
PHP name: saveimagecanvas1.php
<?php

function save_base64_image($base64_image_string, $output_file_without_extension, $path_with_end_slash="" ) {

    $splited = explode(',', substr( $base64_image_string , 5 ) , 2);
    $mime=$splited[0];
    $data=$splited[1];

    $mime_split_without_base64=explode(';', $mime,2);
    $mime_split=explode('/', $mime_split_without_base64[0],2);
    if(count($mime_split)==2)
    {
        $extension=$mime_split[1];
        if($extension=='jpeg')$extension='jpg';
        $output_file_with_extension=$output_file_without_extension.'.'.$extension;
    }
    file_put_contents( $path_with_end_slash . $output_file_with_extension, base64_decode($data) );
    return $output_file_with_extension;
}

if ($_POST['imgData']!="") {

$image = $_POST['imgData'];

$x1=   chr(rand(0,25)+97) ;
$x2=   chr(rand(0,25)+97) ;
$x3=   chr(rand(0,25)+97) ;
$x4=   chr(rand(0,9)+48) ;
$x5=   chr(rand(0,9)+48) ;

$path="./images/".$x1.$x2.$x3.$x4.$x5;

save_base64_image($image, $path, $path_with_end_slash="" );

echo "Image saved - inside the 'images' folder " .$path ;
exit();
}

?>


<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-eKhayi8LEQwp4NKxN+CfCh+3qOVUtJn3QNZ0TciWLP4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div id=ajaxreturn></div>

<canvas id="chart1" width="200" height="100" >

<script>
   var c = document.getElementById("chart1");
   var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.arc(95, 50, 40, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
   ctx.stroke();
</script>



<script>

function submitdata() {

   var canvas = document.getElementById('chart1');
   var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png', 1);
  
         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "saveimagecanvas1.php",
            data: { imgData: imgData },
            success: function(response) {
               document.getElementById('ajaxreturn').innerHTML=response;
            }
        });
}


window.onload = () => {
  submitdata();
}

</script>




Method 2 - do not use ajax, but use form submission to submit data to the PHP itself
PHP name: saveimagecanvas2.php
<?php

function save_base64_image($base64_image_string, $output_file_without_extension, $path_with_end_slash="" ) {

    $splited = explode(',', substr( $base64_image_string , 5 ) , 2);
    $mime=$splited[0];
    $data=$splited[1];

    $mime_split_without_base64=explode(';', $mime,2);
    $mime_split=explode('/', $mime_split_without_base64[0],2);
    if(count($mime_split)==2)
    {
        $extension=$mime_split[1];
        if($extension=='jpeg')$extension='jpg';
        $output_file_with_extension=$output_file_without_extension.'.'.$extension;
    }
    file_put_contents( $path_with_end_slash . $output_file_with_extension, base64_decode($data) );
    return $output_file_with_extension;
}

if ($_POST['imgData']!="") {

$image = $_POST['imgData'];

$x1=   chr(rand(0,25)+97) ;
$x2=   chr(rand(0,25)+97) ;
$x3=   chr(rand(0,25)+97) ;
$x4=   chr(rand(0,9)+48) ;
$x5=   chr(rand(0,9)+48) ;

$path="./images/".$x1.$x2.$x3.$x4.$x5;

save_base64_image($image, $path, $path_with_end_slash="" );

echo "Image saved - inside the 'images' folder " .$path ;

exit();
}

?>


<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-eKhayi8LEQwp4NKxN+CfCh+3qOVUtJn3QNZ0TciWLP4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<canvas id="chart1" width="200" height="100" >

<script>
   var c = document.getElementById("chart1");
   var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.arc(95, 50, 40, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
   ctx.stroke();
</script>



<script>

function submitdata() {

   var canvas = document.getElementById('chart1');
   var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png', 1);
document.getElementById('imgData').value=imgData;
document.getElementById('form1').submit();

}



window.onload = () => {
  submitdata();
}


</script>

<form id=form1 action="#" method=POST>
<input type=hidden name=imgData id=imgData>
</form>


Note: For demonstration, I have drawn a circle in the canvas so that you can have something to save as an image, but of course you can use whatever method to draw the graphic in the canvas.
Result:
the single php file will generate a file known as bse38.png insider the images folder

